# Sampling from uniform distribution row wise

Tags: r, dataframe, random, sampling, uniform

Consider the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:5,
                 x_min = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
                 x_max = c(0.15,0.23,0.38,0.44,0.57))
```

I intend to draw a random sample from a uniform distribution for each row. Why I'm getting the same values for column `y`? Here is what I did:

```
set.seed(12)
df$y <- runif(1, min=df$x_min, max=df$x_max)
```

Output:

```
> df
  id x_min x_max        y
1  1   0.1  0.15 0.103468
2  2   0.2  0.23 0.103468
3  3   0.3  0.38 0.103468
4  4   0.4  0.44 0.103468
5  5   0.5  0.57 0.103468
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `runif(1, min=df$x_min, max=df$x_max)` evaluates to a single number. Replace `1` with `nrow(df)` to ensure the correct number of simulated uniform values.

```r
df <- data.frame(id=1:5,
                 x_min = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
                 x_max = c(0.15,0.23,0.38,0.44,0.57))

set.seed(12)
df$y <- runif(1, min=df$x_min, max=df$x_max)

df
#>   id x_min x_max        y
#> 1  1   0.1  0.15 0.103468
#> 2  2   0.2  0.23 0.103468
#> 3  3   0.3  0.38 0.103468
#> 4  4   0.4  0.44 0.103468
#> 5  5   0.5  0.57 0.103468

set.seed(12)
df$y <- runif(nrow(df), min=df$x_min, max=df$x_max)

df
#>   id x_min x_max         y
#> 1  1   0.1  0.15 0.1034680
#> 2  2   0.2  0.23 0.2245333
#> 3  3   0.3  0.38 0.3754097
#> 4  4   0.4  0.44 0.4107753
#> 5  5   0.5  0.57 0.5118544
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>